# Importing Access query output into Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, import

I am trying to get this code to work, but it doesn't seem to want to pull the string from the getopenfilename command, so I thought I would see if anybody has any ideas on how to reconfigure this code so that it will not treat the getopenfilename string as text and instead as a real path...

```
Sub DB_Import()
    Dim FilePath As Variant

    MsgBox ("Select the path and filename of the correct database")
    FilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(
        SourceType:=0, 
        Source:=Array( _
            "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin; " & _
            "DataSource=FilePath;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties=""""; " & _
            "Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=""""; " & _
            "Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;" & _
            "Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;" & _
            "Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";" & _
            "Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet " & _
            "OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;" & _
            "Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;" & _
            "Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False"), 
        Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable

        .CommandType = xlCmdTable
        .CommandText = Array("Query1")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .SourceDataFile = FilePath
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_ExternalData_1"

        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: "it doesn't seem to want to pull the string from the getopenfilename command". What does that mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the 2nd line to this:

```
"DataSource=" & FilePath & ";Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties=""""; " & _
```

That will insert the value of `FilePath` into your connection string.

Comment: Ah, so you need the ampersands in there?  Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, that's generally how you build a string from literals and variables, e.g., "My name is " & FirstName & " " & LastName & "."

Comment: That is very true.  I don't know why this didn't dawn on me the same way as other literals and variables as you mention.  I've done it dozens of times in loops!

Comment: Probably because there's so much else going on in figuring out how to program QueryTables! It's very rewarding though.